# Burn a CD with Overlapping Sectors

Tags: burning

I want to corrupt a file while burning it on a CD, is there a way to overlap some sectors of that file with another one while burning?

Maybe with the .cue file or a second session instructed to overlap the last couple sectors of the disc?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I'm trying to corrupt a file enough so only one part of it is readable by the machine.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve by *that*? Why not just copy the file and remove some of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ISO [editor](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-isoeditor.htm) to simulate this.

1. Make an ISO
2. Modify the file you want in the way you want
3. Burn the modified ISO